# HashMap manipulation using streams Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Please let me know if there is a possibility of changing the below code in terms of Java 8 using parallel streams?

I am looking for an option to run the "outer for loop" in parallel and finally all the values of stationMap gets collected together?

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> stationMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> routes = function();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : routes.entrySet()) 
{
     Set<Integer> stations = entry.getValue();

      for (Integer station : stations) {
        Set<Integer> temporaryStations = new HashSet<>(stations);
        Set<Integer> stationSet = stationMap.get(station);
        if (stationSet == null) {
          stationSet = new HashSet<>();
          temporaryStations.remove(station);
          stationSet.addAll(temporaryStations);
          stationMap.put(station, stationSet);
        } else {
          temporaryStations.remove(station);
          stationSet.addAll(temporaryStations);
        }
      }
    }
```

More shorter version:

```
routes.forEach((k, stations) -> {
      stations.forEach((station) -> {
        Set<Integer> stationSet = stationMap.get(station);
        if (stationSet == null) {
          stationSet = new HashSet<>();
          stationSet.addAll(stations);
          stationMap.put(station, stationSet);
        } else {
          stationSet.addAll(stations);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: First of all can you please review your code and tell us what you doing? I think this can be simplified. Something is wrong there it seems . The answer will be to use something like this, `routes.keySet()
   .parallelStream()
   .forEach(key ->  {
    final Set<Integer> station = routes.get(key);
    station
     .parallelStream()      
      .forEach(v -> stationMap.put(v, station));;
   });`

Comment: Thank you so much. but there is a small problem with stationMap.put(v, station)....I am actually trying to add the previous stations when i put the station set into the stationMap ("stationSet.addAll(temporaryStations);"). Problem now is its replacing the existing set

Comment: I tried to get the previous stations and add it but its throwing concurrent modification exception :(

Comment: Basically my routes map has <R1, <S1,S2,S3>> and am converting it into <S1, <S2,S3>>, <S2,<S1,S3>> and <S3, <S1,S2>>/.....Where R - Route and S are the stations

Comment: So routes map has more keys from R2, R3......Rn

Comment: Your shorter version doesn’t do the same as the original one.

Comment: @Holger: You mean "temporaryStations.remove(station);". I thought temporary stations are not required. i am gonna stick with <S1, <S1,S2,S3>>. My goal is find the station links from one station to another

Comment: Ok, that comes a bit late. However, my answer also contains solutions gathering `<S1, <S1,S2,S3>>` first and removing `S1` from `<S1,S2,S3>` afterwards, so you can decide whether to skip that post-processing step or not…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the long pre-Java 8 version can be simplified as there is no need to iterate over the entry set, when you are only processing the values and there is no need for code duplication within the two conditional branches:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> routes = function();
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> stationMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Set<Integer> stations: routes.values()) {
    for(Integer station: stations) {
        Set<Integer> temporaryStations = new HashSet<>(stations);
        temporaryStations.remove(station);
        Set<Integer> stationSet = stationMap.get(station);
        if (stationSet == null) {
            stationMap.put(station, temporaryStations);
        } else {
            stationSet.addAll(temporaryStations);
        }
    }
}
```

using Java 8 features, you may get the improved variant:

```
routes.values().forEach(stations ->
    stations.forEach(station -> {
        Set<Integer> temporaryStations = new HashSet<>(stations);
        temporaryStations.remove(station);
        Set<Integer> old = stationMap.putIfAbsent(station, temporaryStations);
        if(old!=null) old.addAll(stations);
    })
);
```

though it might be simpler to first merge all values and remove the keys afterwards in one step:

```
routes.values().forEach(stations ->
    stations.forEach(station -> 
        stationMap.computeIfAbsent(station, key -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(stations)
    )
);
stationMap.forEach((k,set) -> set.remove(k));
```

It’s possible to formulate an equivalent (parallel) Stream operation:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> stationMap=routes.values().parallelStream()
    .flatMap(stations -> stations.stream().map(station -> {
        Set<Integer> temporaryStations = new HashSet<>(stations);
        temporaryStations.remove(station);
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(station, temporaryStations);
    })
).collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a; }));
```

but this may also be simpler when removing the keys from the value set in a post processing step:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> stationMap=routes.values().parallelStream()
    .flatMap(stations -> stations.stream().map(station -> 
        new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(station, new HashSet<>(stations))
    )
).collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a; }));
stationMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> e.getValue().remove(e.getKey()));
```

or you use a custom collector instead of `flatMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> stationMap=routes.values().parallelStream()
    .collect(HashMap::new,
            (map,stations) -> stations.forEach(station -> 
                map.computeIfAbsent(station, key -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(stations)
            ),
            (m1,m2) -> m2.forEach((k,v)->m1.merge(k, v, (a,b)->{a.addAll(b); return a;})));
stationMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> e.getValue().remove(e.getKey()));
```

this might be more efficient as it doesn’t need the temporary `Map.Entry` instances.